# The type or namespace name 'HITAssistContext' could not be found

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am creating a web form in Visual Studio 2012. The form is to enter data into a table using Entity Framework. It works perfectly when testing it in Visual Studio.

But when it is uploaded to Localhost, I get the following error: The type or namespace name 'HITAssistContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

'HITAssistContext' is the connection string to the database modle

HITAssistContext DBconnection = new HITAssistContext();

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you release the application? It sounds like you didn't deploy some required dependencies.

Comment: I first setup a virtual site in iis and then I deploy in VS with publish method: File System and point to the physical location to the virtual site.

Answer (score 0):

place the HITAssistContext.dll from your project files into 
osdriveletter:\windir\System32\Inetsrv